# Apply for a UK residence card

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, netherlands

Under the [eligibility](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/eligibility) rules for applying for a [UK residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/overview):

> You can apply for a residence card if you’re both:
>
> from outside the European Economic Area (EEA) the family member, or
>   extended family member, of an EEA national who is a permanent resident
>   or ‘qualified person’

I am from outside the European Economic Area but I have relative members: my aunt, uncle and cousin who are Netherlands citizens. My aunt is a former Malayisian (now should be considered as Dutch after more than 30 years living in Netherlands), while my uncle and cousin are Dutch.

So am I eligible for a UK residence card? But they don't live in the UK. They live in Netherlands.

But this is unclear: `extended family member, of an EEA national who is a permanent resident` - is it a `permanent resident` of UK or of any country of EEA?

Comment: The residence card evidences one's right to live in the UK under directive 2004/38/UK.  That right depends on having an EU (or EEA or Swiss) relative living in the UK, as well as having a relationship that qualifies under the directive.  With an aunt, uncle, or cousin, the relationship would qualify only if you are dependent on the relative, or a member of the relative's household.  So even if your Dutch relative were to move to the UK, you wouldn't likely qualify for a residence card. (Also, your aunt won't automatically be Dutch just for having lived there for a long time.)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately they need to be both an EU citizen *and* a permanent resident of the UK.

Comment: Or they can be a "qualified person" -- which also implies residence in the UK.